# Assign a changed function to another variable and get different body with same name

Tags: javascript, function

I declare a function

```
function hello(){console.log("Hello World!");}
```

then assign it to a variable

```
newHello = hello;
```

In Console I get function definition for hello and newHello functions.

```
>newHello = hello;
ƒ hello(){console.log("Hello World!");}
>hello;
ƒ hello(){console.log("Hello World!");}
```

After that i change hello function and assign it to new variable as bellow:

```
function hello(){console.log("Hello World Changed!");}
newNewHello=hello;
```

I get function definition for hello and newHello and newNewHello functions and receive follow results:

```
>hello
ƒ hello(){console.log("Hello World Changed!");}
>newHello
ƒ hello(){console.log("Hello World!");}
>newNewHello
ƒ hello(){console.log("Hello World Changed!");}
```

Why name of these function is equal but body of them if not equal and how it work in background if javascript language?

Answer (score 0):

When you write `newHello = hello;`, you aren't saying "From now on, `newHello` will be a reference to whatever may be named `hello` at some point in the future when I look at the `newHello` variable again."

Instead, you are saying "`newHello` will now become a reference to whatever is named `hello` *right now*."

So when you later change `hello` to be something else, it doesn't affect `newHello` at all. `newHello` is still a reference to whatever you assigned to it previously.

Put another way, after that first assignment, you don't have this (where I'm using → to mean "is a reference to":

`newHello` → `hello` → (your original function)

Instead you have this:

`hello` → (your original function)
`newHello` → (your original function)

In other words, both `hello` refer directly to the original function. So changing `hello` to reference a different function doesn't affect `newHello`.

Comment: I want to know: how javascript do this in background? for example by assign a unique hash code to any function or another way?

Comment: You could almost think of it like that, or you could think of it like a pointer. But the term you want is "reference", and how a reference is implemented under the hood isn't known to us. When you say `a = b` in JavaScript, you are making `a` become a _reference_ to whatever the value of `b` is at the time you do the `=`.

Comment: Note that the individual functions retained their original name of "hello" when logged - this part isn't really covered explictly in the answer.

Comment: @nnnnnn Are you referring to the fact that inside each of the two different `hello` functions, `arguments.callee` or `arguments.callee.name` will still show that the name is `hello`, if those are supported? That is true, but of course these are gone in strict mode.

Comment: I'm referring to how they appeared when logged in the console, as shown in the question.

Comment: Yes, that's the internal name of the function, and it doesn't change once the function is created. Assigning a reference to the function into a variable of any name doesn't change the function's internal name, and creating a new and different function that happens to use the same name doesn't change the internal name either. The console and stack trace show the internal name for debugging purposes, but it generally isn't useful information from within JavaScript code, and in strict mode isn't visible to JavaScript code at all.

Comment: In other words, when you log `hello` or `newHello` or any other variable in the console, the dev tools display whatever that variable refers to - the _contents_ of the variable. In this case that is a function, so if the function has a name, that name is displayed regardless of what name you used to get there.

Comment: And you can easily have two functions with the same name, for example enter this in the console: `var f1 = function ff() { return 1; }; var f2 = function ff() { return 2; };` and then enter `f1` and `f2` on separate lines. You will see that these are two distinct functions with different return values, although the same name `ff` is displayed for both.

Comment: I think this assignment is in object definition and any function create an object that different from other. so name of these functions are same but body of them aren't, then we have two different functions